# angular2firebase - multiple instances using Angular 6

Tags: angularfire2, angular6

I'm upgrading to `Angular 6` using `AngularFire2`. My app referenced 2 `Firebase` projects using code like this to create the database reference:

```
public initFirebaseApp(config: FirebaseAppConfig, firebaseAppName: string) {
        this._db = new AngularFireDatabase(_firebaseAppFactory(config, firebaseAppName));
    }
```

This code is now broken. I get this:

```
ERROR in src/app/services/firebase.service.ts(24,25): error TS2554: Expected 5 arguments, but got 1.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularFire now support many more configuration objects via Injection now, which is why it's expecting more arguments. It currently takes:

```
constructor(
  @Inject(FirebaseOptionsToken) options:FirebaseOptions,
  @Optional() @Inject(FirebaseNameOrConfigToken) nameOrConfig:string|FirebaseAppConfig|undefined,
  @Optional() @Inject(RealtimeDatabaseURL) databaseURL:string,
  @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object,
  zone: NgZone
)
```

Though now that we support dependency injection, I wouldn't suggest directly initializing like you are to support multiple apps. [We have an open issue for documenting this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1026) but you can now inject different `FirebaseOptions` via the `FirebaseOptionsToken` into different components, if you need multiple databases in the same component use something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AngularFireDatabaseAlpha extends AngularFireDatabase { }

@Injectable()
export class AngularFireDatabaseBeta extends AngularFireDatabase { }


export function AngularFireDatabaseAlphaFactory(platformId: Object, zone: NgZone): Project1AngularFireAuth {
  return new AngularFireDatabaseAlpha(environment.firebase[0], 'alpha', undefined, platformId, zone)
}
export function AngularFireDatabaseBetaFactory(platformId: Object, zone: NgZone): Project2AngularFireAuth {
  return new AngularFireDatabaseBeta(environment.firebase[1], 'beta', undefined, platformId, zone)
}


@NgModule({
  ...,
  providers: [
    ...,
    { provide: AngularFireDatabaseAlpha, deps: [PLATFORM_ID, NgZone], useFactory: AngularFireDatabaseAlphaFactory },
    { provide: AngularFireDatabaseBeta, deps: [PLATFORM_ID, NgZone], useFactory: AngularFireDatabaseBetaFactory },
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

Then you can just rely on Dependency Injection to get `AngularFireDatabaseAlpha` and `AngularFireDatabaseBeta` into your component.

Comment: Got idea from this answer to figure out the solution for my case here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922195/can-not-have-access-to-multiple-google-firestore-db-in-angular-6-application-wit

Comment: Other searched related items just to share: angularfire2 issue #1240 (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1240) or #1305 (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1305).

Comment: Have you tried deploying or launching the app in prod mode. When angular's optimizer is used the dependency injection crashes on pre-build of the app

Comment: This solution is not working anymore because AngularFireAuth expects more parameters now see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71272920/how-to-have-multi-project-firebase-using-angularfire