# Can not have access to multiple Google Firestore DB in Angular 6 application with angularfire2

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire5

I try to have access to multiple Google Firestore DB from my Angular 6 application through angularfire2 package.

I initialized multiple instance of AngularFireModule in app.module.ts but couldn't find a way to have access to both DBs:

```html
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
 ...
  ],
  imports: [
 ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(coolStoreConfig, 'coolStore'),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(perfectStoreConfig, 'perfectStore'),
 ...
  ],
  ...
 })
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some searches around, the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473945/angular2firebase-multiple-instances-using-angular-6/50476192#50476192) could help a lot:
[angular2firebase - multiple instances using Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473945/angular2firebase-multiple-instances-using-angular-6/50476192#50476192)

looks like creating providers for each instance can be a good idea

```html
...
{ provide: AngularfirestoreCoolStoreService, deps: [PLATFORM_ID, NgZone], useFactory: AngularfirestoreCoolStoreFactory },
{ provide: AngularfirestorePerfectStoreService, deps: [PLATFORM_ID, NgZone], useFactory: AngularfirestorePerfectStoreFactory }
...
```

I created a stalkblitz which shows how it works:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-or2ehb

Comment: Any other suggestion or workaround would be appreciated and useful for community. Just to share angularfire2 issue #1240 (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1240) or #1305 (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1305) which I found them similar and interesting.

Comment: No other idea and as it works then just I picked it up as answer for now.