# How can I connect two databases with @angular/fire?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

I'm trying to connect to firestore databases to my angular frontent. I've tried by adding a secound AngularFireModule, with no success!

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent], // Autosize
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicRatingModule, // Put ionic-rating module here
    AppRoutingModule,

    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    AuthenticatedGuard,
    ProducerGuard,
    AdminGuard,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I'm using @agular/fire version 5.2.3
And angular version 7
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a potential duplicate of :

- [Can not have access to multiple Google Firestore DB in Angular 6 application with angularfire2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922195/can-not-have-access-to-multiple-google-firestore-db-in-angular-6-application-wit/51922426#51922426)
- [angular2firebase - multiple instances using Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473945/angular2firebase-multiple-instances-using-angular-6/50476192#50476192)

Please have a look also at these 2 issues on GitHub :

- https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1240
- https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1305#issuecomment-361884177

And this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-or2ehb) made by [Farhad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2345084/farhad) on previous items.

As it is mentioned in answers above, you can manually provide multiples instances of Firestore inside `NgModule`:

```
...
{ provide: AngularfirestoreCoolStoreService, deps: [PLATFORM_ID, NgZone], useFactory: AngularfirestoreCoolStoreFactory },
{ provide: AngularfirestorePerfectStoreService, deps: [PLATFORM_ID, NgZone], useFactory: AngularfirestorePerfectStoreFactory }
...
```